# Règles pour l'utilisation de l'auxiliaire être ou avoir avec "se faire plaisir"?

Tags: verbes-pronominaux, auxiliaires

Il semble que l'auxiliaire change suivant le complément pour la construction verbale "se faire plaisir". Y a-t-il une règle pour cela? Et comment l'expliquer?

Par exemple:

> je me suis fait plaisir

auxiliaire : **être**

> je lui ai fait plaisir

auxiliaire: **avoir**

Bescherelle et Grevisse semblent muets sur le sujet, quelqu'un aurait-il une explication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans ton premier exemple

> je me suis fait plaisir

**se faire plaisir** se conjugue avec l'auxiliaire être parce qu'il s'agit d'un verbe pronominal.

Dans ton deuxième exemple

> je lui ai fait plaisir

le verbe n'est pas **se faire** **plaisir** mais **faire plaisir à quelqu'un**. Donc, il s'agit d'un verbe transitif et par conséquent il se conjugue avec l'auxiliaire avoir.

Comment: merci pour cette réponse claire et précise !

Answer (score 1):

C'est très simple :

- **Tous** les verbes à la **forme pronominale** se conjuguent avec l'auxiliaire *être* (quel que soit l'auxiliaire sélectionné pour les autres formes) :

  - les réfléchis : *il s'est vu dans la glace*
  - les réciproques : *ils se sont battus*
  - les intrinsèquement pronominaux : *il s'est évanoui*

Il serait étonnant que les deux références citées soient muettes sur ce sujet.

Comment: je confirme que Bescherelle mentionne bien l'utilisation de **être** comme auxiliaire des verbes à la forme pronominale. Il fallait *juste* l'ouvrir à la bonne page.